# Can the rails testing environment respond to http requests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, testing

I have a nodejs pupeteer script that does client http calls to the rails server to produce PDF files of the web page the rails server generate.

The rails server later processes those PDF files for sending.

I would like to produce the PDF files from data in my testing environment.   But is the testing environment capable of responding to http calls?   Do I have to specify a different port or server address?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this... write a request spec. Here's an example from my own code. It's testing the scenario where a PrintNode server is updating the print status of a print job using the PrintNode webhooks feature:

```rb
require 'rails_helper'

describe "KioskOrdersWebhookController"  do
  describe "when webhook post is authenticated" do
    let(:print_job_id){ [rand(10**7..10**8), rand(10**7..10**8)] }
    let(:params){ 
      {"_json"=>[
        {"type"=>"print job state",
         "accountId"=>410075,
         "foo" => 8899,
         "controllingAccountId"=>410075,
         "createdAt"=>"2024-01-06T05:11:05.15745779Z",
         "data"=>{"message"=>"done",
                  "printJobId"=> print_job_id[0],
                  "state"=>"sent to client",
                  "uid"=>"3558f5de-df9a-4375-9f66-9c27185f4616"}
      }]
      }
    }
    let(:valid_headers){
      {"HTTP_X_PRINTNODE_WEBHOOK_SECRET"  => PRINTNODE_WEBHOOK_SECRET}
    }

    describe "receive incoming status message" do
      it "updates the kiosk order print_status attribute" do
        post kiosk_orders_webhook_path, params: params, headers: valid_headers
        expect(first_kiosk_order.reload.print_status).to eq 'received'
        expect(second_kiosk_order.reload.print_status).to eq 'sent'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The `post` is the actual simulated post from the external service... and I set expectations after as to what should happen.